# How to check if a message was sent in the right channel

Tags: python, discord

I want my discord bot to delete the message if it is not in the bot-commands channel but I'm unsure of one thing. I tried:

`if message.channel == "bot-commands"`

and

`if message.channel == 531183259250458636`

but they both didn't work.

Comment: You're looking for `message.channel.name` or `message.channel.id`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

`if message.channel.name == "bot-commands"`

## Why This Works

This works because if we look in documentation, we can see that message.channel returns `TextChannel`, `DMChannel`, or `GroupDMChannel`. In your case, it'll be returning `TextChannel`. If we look in the properties of `TextChannel`, there is a property called `name` which is a string. Therefore, we can compare this to another string.